# Delay in Changing state in step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step functions which is taking time in changing state.I have a glue job in my step function.Sometimes I see that even though the glue job execution is complete the state defining that glue job in step function is not updated.Upon observing the step function I see that when the glue job is finished within the 15th Minute of the hour the state changes immediately while when it crosses the 15th Minute, the update to the state happens in 20th Minute.So My question is Doesn't the step function keep checking the status of glue job?.Does it update the status of glue job every 5th Minute?

Comment: Hi @ashutosh-rai did you find any insight on this. I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to a query similar to this on [AWS re:post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUFFlHcbvIQFe-bS3RAi7TWA/a-glue-job-in-a-step-function-is-taking-so-long-to-continue-the-next-step).

> By design, the polling schedule is once per minute for the first 10 minutes, and every 5 minutes thereafter.

So yes - it is every 5th minute as you inferred. The post doesn't indicate there is any workaround for this at present.

**Edit: Workaround**

If you want your step function to respond more timeously, you could start the glue job asynchronously, and poll it yourself using a combination of the Wait State and the Glue:GetJobRun State.

[Here is a link to a sample project that describes this mechanism.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html)